# Prove using generating functions the equality of amount of solutions for provided equation with two given groups of limitations

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

At first, I hope the title for the post is fine, because I wasn't able to sum up the question to a better title.

Anyways, this is the problem: I've got to prove that $a_n=b_n$ for every $n$ while:

- $a_n$ is for the amount of nonnegative solutions of the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ and when $x_2$ is even, and $x_3$ doesn't divide by 3.
- $b_n$ stands for the amount of nonnegative solutions for the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ and when $x_1$ is positive, and $x_3$ is dividable by 3.

this is what I've thought of until now:

- for $b_n$ - I think I can represent it using the following generating functions:
  $$(x+x^2+x^3+...)(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+...)$$
- for $a_n$ - I think I can represent it using the following generating functions:
  $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)(1+x^2+x^4+...)(x+x^2+x^4+x^5+x^7+x^8+...)$$
  that equals (**I afraid i'm wrong at this step**):
  $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)(1+x^2+x^4+...)((x+x^4+x^7+...)+(x^2+x^5+x^8+...))$$
  that equals:
  $$x(1+x+x^3+x^6+...)(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)(1+x^2+x^4+...)(1+x)$$

is it correct what I did? I'm pretty sure about $b_n$, however $a_n$ doesn't seem to be correct. (should I use a solution based on the complementary, meaning, instead of looking for $x_3$ which isn't dividable by 3, to look for $x_3$ without any limitations and then to subtract the options when $x_3$ is dividable by 3? is there a more straightforward path?)

Thank you,

Comment: You get proper spacing if you use `\ldots` instead of `...` (or better yet, `\cdots` to have the dots on the level of the operator).

Answer (score 2):

This is all correct, and a good way to solve the problem. Now all that's left to show is

$$
x(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots)(1+x)=x+x^2+x^3+\cdots\;.
$$

Comment: You mean that $a_n=x(1+x+x^3+x^6+...)(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)(1+x^2+x^4+...)(1+x)$ is correct?

Comment: @Ami: Yes. ${}$

Comment: as I know from calculus, it's **not** allowed to split infinite sums. why here is it legal to do so? (where I splitted $(x+x^2+x^4+x^5+x^7+x^8+...)$ to $((x+x^4+x^7+...)+(x^2+x^5+x^8+...))$)

Comment: @Ami: Well, you never said a word about convergence in all of this, I got the impression that you were merely interested in manipulating formal power series. You'd have to restrict the whole thing to $|x|\lt1$ to let it make sense in terms of convergent series. In that case, the two convergent series $x+x^4+x^7+\cdots$ and $x^2+x^5+x^8+\cdots$ can be combined; this is a general property of convergent series; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties).

Comment: so to make sure - only convergent infinite series could be splitted as I did? if it's correct, is it because the idea (and definition) of the generating functions? that an infinite series could be written as a finite function? (i.e. $\Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k \equiv \frac{1}{1-x}$) $$$$
as I get it, there're no divergent series in the field of generating functions in descrete math, so does it make this discussion irrelevant? Thanks